# Load the contents of popup(has a <s:form>) from struts2 action

Tags: jsp, struts2, struts2-jquery-plugin

I have a jsp page which has a popup (popup is a div in jsp). When I click a link in jsp I want to open a popup with the form in popup being loaded with values coming from struts2 action.

I explored strust2-jQuery plugin, but didn't find a solution to this.

How can I do this.

Please help.

I tried this with strust2-jQuery , but it didn't work :

MarkettingDetails.jsp :

```
<p><sj:a id="link1" href="loadMDEditPopUp.action" targets="market-info-new-popup1" >AIG123 </sj:a></p>
```

struts.xml:

```
<action name="loadMDEditPopUp" class="com.marsh.pdcs.controller.MarkettingDetails" 
       method="loadMDEditPopUp">            
    <result name="success">/jsp/MarkettingDetails/marketInfoDetailsEditPopup.jsp</result>       
</action>
```

market-info-new-popup1 :

this is a div in MarkettingDetails.jsp , which I dispaly as a popup with css styles.

`<sj:link>` does give a call to struts2 action , but as a result it goes back
 to  MarkettingDetails.jsp without opening popup

Comment: What is `market-info-new-popup1` ? Show the missing MarkettingDetails.jsp snippet

Comment: Combine it with prepopulated event which is capable to handle the results.